# Pandas dataframe drop rows based on attributes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with date objects. I want to remove rows with certain years and months, let's say February. What is the Pythonic way to do it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2020-01-01','2020-02-02','2020-03-03','2020-04-04'],columns=['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.date
```

This seems like too much typing and leaves a NaN value.

```
df["dates"] = pd.Series([date for date in df["dates"].values if date.month!=2]
        dates
0  2020-01-01
1  2020-03-03
2  2020-04-04
3         NaN
```

If I try to access attributes of all objects in a series I get an error.

```
df = df.drop(df[df.dates.month==2].index)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Comparing with a range seems too much typing and I don't know how to combine the conditions.

```
df = df.drop(df[df.dates >= pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01') and df.dates < pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01')].index)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dt` accessor but it requires the column to be of type `pd.Timestamp`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2020-01-01','2020-02-02','2020-03-03','2020-04-04'],columns=['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']) # removed the .dt.date

# Remove rows whose month are Feb, Mar or Apr, in 2018 & 2019 only
df[~(df['dates'].dt.month.isin([2,3,4]) & df['dates'].dt.month.isin(2018, 2019))]
```

Comment: Great! How to add the condition for a year?

Comment: you wrote .month twice and didn't use square brackets for year.
df[~(df['dates'].dt.year.isin([2020]) &  df['dates'].dt.month.isin([2]))] . But even then it returns the right answer, but doesn't change the dataframe. If I assign it to the dataframe it replaces the removed rows with NaT.

Comment: I've solved it based on your answer:
`code
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']) # removed the .dt.date

def date_needed(date):
    return ~(date.dt.year.isin([2020]) & date.dt.month.isin([2]))

df = df[date_needed(df['date'])]
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
`